# Javascript While Loop with Form Values

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, while-loop

This is a snippet from something really simple I'm working on (unfortunately, I do not have much experience in Javascript). Basically, I need to print the values of multiple dynamic text fields in order (I'm assuming dynamic is the right word; more text boxes can be added or taken away depending on how many are needed). They are labeled like so:

```
<li><input type="text" name="feature_1" id="feature_1" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="feature_2" id="feature_2" /></li>
etc
etc
```

I've been using this to try and get the input values from the text boxes.

```
amount = 4; //this is actually the total number of text boxes used
var count = 1;
while (count <= amount) {
        var feature_text = "form.feature_" + count + ".value";
        text += ("<li>" + feature_text + "</li>\n");
        count++;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this outputs

```
<li>form.feature_1.value</li>
<li>form.feature_2.value</li>
<li>form.feature_3.value</li>
<li>form.feature_4.value</li>
```

instead of

```
<li>Value 1</li>
<li>Value 2</li>
<li>Value 3</li>
<li>Value 4</li>
```

What do I do to get "feature_text" to pull the values instead of outputting a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
var feature_text = document.getElementById("feature_" + count).value;
```

Comment: that did it. good lord i couldn't understand that. thank you very much

Comment: you could also do `text += '<li>'+form['feature_'+count].value+'</li>\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
text = document.getElementById("form.feature_" + count).value;
```

Comment: Just make sure you're appending to the `text` variable, `+=`, and not re-assigning the value, `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("theButton")

amount = 4; //this is actually the total number of text boxes used
var count = 1;
while (count <= amount) {
        var feature_text = "form.feature_" + count;
        text += ("<li>" + document.getElementById(feature_text).value + "</li>\n");
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a string instead of the actual value because that is what you are creating currently with:

```
var feature_text = "form.feature_" + count + ".value";
```

The use of the quotes [""] around the text creates a string value, instead of referring to the DOM element.

Refer to the elements by the actual IDs if possible:

```
var feature_text = document.getElementById('feature_' + count).value;
```

A more complete example that moves the code to a function and executes using the onclick event handler:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="feature_1" id="feature_1" /></li> 
    <li><input type="text" name="feature_2" id="feature_2" /></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getValues()" />

<div id="output"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getValues(){     
    var amount = 2; 
    var count = 1; 
    var text = ['<ul>'];

    for(var i=1; i <= amount; i++) {
        var ele = document.getElementById("feature_" + i);
        text[i] = "<li>" + ele.value + "</li>";
    }
    text.push('</ul>');

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text.join('');
}
```

I modified the while-loop to use a for-loop and switched to an array for your `text` variable for increased optimization.

You could condense it further by not assigning the element to a variable at all since you are only getting its value:

```
text[i] = "<li>" + document.getElementById("feature_" + i).value + "</li>";
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ACVFq/